# How to store the Firestore data in a list of objects?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all document in my firestore collection and then create Artist objects with it.
I can get the data from firestore and display it, but when I add an artist to my list it remains empty

```
class Artist{
  late String id;
  late String name;
  late String year;
  Artist(this.id, this.name, this.year);
}
```

```
class ArtistsService{
  Future getAllArtists() async {
    Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> firestoreResult = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data').get();

    late List<Artiste> localList = [];

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('data').get().then((docSnapshot) {
      for (var i = 1; i <= docSnapshot.docs.length -1; i++) {
        String id = docSnapshot.docs[i].id;
        String annee = docSnapshot.docs[i]["annee"].toString();
        String name = docSnapshot.docs[i]["artistes"].toString();
        print(id); // It works
        print(annee); // It works
        print(name); // It works
        localList.add(new Artiste(id,name,annee)); // It don't works
      }
    });
    print("LIST : " + localList.toString());


    return firestoreResult;
  }
}
```

Data are print but list is empty, why?

```
I/flutter (27623): 3t36pe5ipPXxkhfh2lz7
I/flutter (27623): 2004
I/flutter (27623): Redrama

I/flutter (27623): 6lZTV9gu0DIlXCgxjVWu
I/flutter (27623): 2004
I/flutter (27623): Lars Horntveth

...
I/flutter (27623): LIST : []
```

Answer (score 1):

try change the line where you mention `It don't works` to the code below. By doing this you are actually storing the value you get from docSnapshot into the variable of class `Artiste`

```
localList.add(
   new Artiste(
    id : id, // this id is the id that you get from docSnapshot
    name : name, // this name is the name that you get from docSnapshot
    year : annee, // this annee is the anne that you get from docSnapshot
   )
);
```